# 3D Area Chart SSRS Report 3rd Axis

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I would like to have a 3D Area Chart in my SSRS Report, which contains 3 Dimensions like in Excel to display the `month,` `volume` and `categories`, the data of these three columns.
It should look like this example below (Pic just an example, taken from Google):
[image]

The problem now is,I seem not to be able to add the third axis to display month in ssrs. Does anybody here have a solution for that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can achieve your example without buying some additional chart types.

The closest I could get (in the 10 minutes I had spare) was to setup a 3d Area chart as follows... (note: my dataset only contains year, month and amount for simplicity)

[image]

Which, based on some sample data I had... gives the following..

[image]

Comment: Yeah I also think without purchasing some additional plugin is this not really possible, what is wished here is time variables to be displayed on a z-axix. I feel the so called 3d area chart in ssrs is just a 3d display of 2d chart, because it doesn't allow a third axis :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: I've used Nevron charts for a project years ago. Very customisable and they have a surface chart like you want. Be aware that you also need to install on the server as well as the development machine. So, if this is in-house you'll be OK but if this is for a client then they will have to install the additional components on their report server.
https://www.nevron.com/products-reporting-services-chart-gallery-charting-types-grid-surface-chart.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the Info, I have also found Nevron when i googled for solution, for that, both my boss and my client need to agree I guess:)